# Jquery .has("tag") filter shows that tags that dont have element have them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to filter `li` tags that contain `ul` tags through Jquery. Jquery `.has("tag")` filter shows that tags that dont have element have them.

[image: Jquery code]

```js
$(".mobile_menu>ul>li").click(function(event) {
  /* Act on the event */
  console.log("clicked");
  if($(this).has(".ul")){
   console.log("it has ul");
   console.log($(this));
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile_menu">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2
      <ul class="none">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: try with `.has("ul").length > 0`

Comment: What is your question

Comment: Please use backticks, not bold italics, if you want to highlight code-like things such as `li`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it, use `$(this).has("ul").length > 0`

first remove the dot from `.has(".ul")` since `ul` is not a `class`.

`<- credit to T.J.Crowder ->`

You can even make it a bit shorter and use `$(this).has("ul").length`

`has` "*returns a jQuery object, not a flag. jQuery objects are always truthy.*"

```js
$(".mobile_menu>ul>li").click(function(event) {
  /* Act on the event */
  console.log("clicked");
  if ($(this).has("ul").length > 0) {
    console.log("it has ul");
    console.log($(this));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile_menu">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2
      <ul class="none">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Very true, Adding this to solution

Comment: (Thanks for the credit, but there's no need in this case. It's good of you to think of it, though.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agree but I'm not that fast at writing since I need to make sure I'm spelling it correctly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for your help and wise words

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` and `length` to check if the current `li` has `ul`:

```js
$(".mobile_menu>ul>li").click(function(event) {
  /* Act on the event */
  console.log("clicked");
  if ($(this).find("ul.none").length) {
    console.log("it has ul");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile_menu">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2
      <ul class="none">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```